# Can i change the conditions dynamically when i use storm as a filter?

Tags: apache-storm

I've been reading about the document of Storm and searching in google about my question,but i still don't find the way to deal with my use case by storm.

My use case: I use storm as a filter,but the condition of the filter will be changed by the client dynamically, then storm will output the result which is fit the current filter condition.

what confused me is how can client comunicate with storm to change the filter condition dynamically ? or am I just looking at the wrong thing? If so, what alternatives do you propose for this use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since prepared spout/bolt can store state, it is a solution to put your filter condition into them.

And there are multiple ways to change them dynamically. For example:

1. sending some special tuple into the topology, which indicates the changes.
2. store the filter condition in zookeeper or something like that. Store a curator listener in your bolt, which can apply changes on the fly.